# Android, sending push notification to mulitple users

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I want to send push notifications to all users in my database, but with this code I only send a notification to the last user in my database.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");

$message = $_POST["message"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$path = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$server_key = "***";
$sql = "SELECT fcm_token FROM User";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $headers = array("Authorization:key=" .$server_key, "Content-Type:application/json");
    $fields = array("to"=>$row["fcm_token"], "notification"=>array("title"=>$title, "body"=>$message));
    $payload = json_encode($fields);
    $curl_session = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IFRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
}

$result = curl_exec($curl_session);

curl_close($curl_session);
mysqli_close($connect);


$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Anybody knows a solution?

Comment: `$result = curl_exec($curl_session);`

is not in your `while` cycle.

Comment: @PavelStrelchenko Doesn't work like this: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Comment: so, you need to declare another variable =) like this: `$curl_result = curl_exec($curl_session);`

Comment: @PavelStrelchenko Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to collect all the FCM tokens and use `registration_ids` to make sure you only send one HTTP request to the FCM server. You can find the full FCM HTTP protocol [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");

$message = $_POST["message"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$path = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$server_key = "***";
$sql = "SELECT fcm_token FROM User";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$tokens = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tokens[] = $row["fcm_token"];
}

$headers = array("Authorization:key=" . $server_key, "Content-Type:application/json");
$fields = array(
    "registration_ids" => $tokens,
    "notification" => array("title" => $title, "body" => $message)
);
$payload = json_encode($fields);

$curl_session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IFRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

$curl_result = curl_exec($curl_session);
curl_close($curl_session);

mysqli_close($connect);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exec your request inside your while loop. So, you need to rewrite your code in the following way:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");

$message = $_POST["message"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$path = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$server_key = "***";
$sql = "SELECT fcm_token FROM User";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $headers = array("Authorization:key=" .$server_key, "Content-Type:application/json");
    $fields = array("to"=>$row["fcm_token"], "notification"=>array("title"=>$title, "body"=>$message));
    $payload = json_encode($fields);
    $curl_session = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IFRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

    $curl_result = curl_exec($curl_session);
    curl_close($curl_session);
}

mysqli_close($connect);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: I get now two notifications on my target devices.

Comment: @lukas-dieser Are you confident, that your SQL script returns correct number of rows and different fcm_tokens?

Comment: My script returns the two fcm_tokens I need (there are only two), every token only once.

Comment: Please, try editted code (I've moved `curl_close($curl_session)` into loop)